# move_uploaded_file() permission denied even though permissions look correct

Tags: php, apache, rhel

I am moving uploaded files to a directory inside the html folder(RHEL with apache) using move_uploaded_file().

If I move to www/uploads this will work, but if I use www/html/bla/documents I get a permission error.

```
...failed to open stream: Permission denied ...
...Unable to move ...

      File: ‘../../uploads/’
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 2242820     Links: 2
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1002/developer)   Gid: ( 1002/developer)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
Access: 2018-06-06 07:40:27.662812092 +0000
Modify: 2018-06-06 07:42:00.868583357 +0000
Change: 2018-06-06 07:42:00.868583357 +0000
 Birth: -

  File: ‘documents’
  Size: 6               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 35485731    Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1002/developer)   Gid: ( 1002/developer)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
Access: 2018-06-06 09:54:08.855892855 +0000
Modify: 2018-06-06 09:54:07.803861541 +0000
Change: 2018-06-06 09:54:07.803861541 +0000
 Birth: -

[developer@vm-pomit01 pomit]$ groups apache
apache : apache developer
[developer@vm-pomit01 pomit]$ groups root
root : root developer
```

What am I missing here in terms of permissions?

Comment: `Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)` is missing a `w`. Usually not a fan of this, but does it work with permissions `0777`? If yes, for some reason your account is not in the correct group.

Comment: Not sure, but you might need   `0777` permission for upload

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix it.